# Defining an array of string to string map in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have an interface that accepts `{ [key:string]: string }`.
I want to test several cases for it. For this I want to define an array containing my test cases as follows:

```
const tests: [ {[key: string]: string} ] = [{
  "A": "B"
}, {
  "C": "D"
}]
```

But it will not compile because Typescript is assuming those inline objects are types in of themselves.

> Type '[{ A: string; }, { C: string; }]' is not assignable to type '[{
> [key: string]: string; }]'.   Source has 2 element(s) but target
> allows only 1.

Comment: try it like this: `{[key: string]: string}[]`

Comment: `Array<{[key: string]: string}>` should also work. The problem is that your declaration only allows one element inside of the array, yet you pass 2 elements into it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not how you type arrays of a particular type in TypeScript. The following gives no errors [in the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCm0IC4YG8DaBreBPV0ATgJZgDmAugVCeQL4YUwC8MGaAsAFAwwBEAQT6o+AIT7c6AGnTdefAMLD+AEQlc6FbkA):

```js
const tests: {[key: string]: string}[] = [{
  "A": "B"
}, {
  "C": "D"
}]
```

Comment: `[ {[key: string]: string} ] ` is definitely an `Array`, but only with one element inside of it ;)

Comment: @MikeS. TS calls that a tuple. Yes, it accepts an array for it but the type itself has a distinct name.

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this:

```
const tests: {[key: string]: string}[] = [{
  "A": "B"
}, {
  "C": "D"
}]
```

Doing it like you did, `[{[key: string]: string}]`, means it should be an array with one object inside.